# extension=php_sockets.dll , Doesn't enable Socket

Tags: php, sockets

I am using Godaddy Linux Shared Hosting. I want to start socket in php. while googling I found

```
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sockets.so
```

to be uncommented. I put php5.ini and php.ini files to my server to override default settings and put above directives in it. Yet its not working.

you can see my `phpgetinfo()` output at , [MyWebsite](http://www.harsh-it.com/getInfo.php)

When I call  `socket_create()` function , it gives me an error **`Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create()`**

I contacted GoDaddy Customer Care but they said everything is fine from their side ,and my code is incorrect. But I haven't put anything other than just calling to this function.

Kindly Help me to solve the problem.

---

**UPDATE**

I raised a ticket for above problem and go daddy replied me

> PHP Sockets are not supported on Web Hosting plans. If you require that functionality you will want to review the Virtual Private Server or Dedicated Server plans. Our servers are sold with the understanding that administration duties, security and management of the server are your responsibility. For more information on the servers we offer please review the following.
>
> Dedicated servers
>
> Virtual Private Servers
>
> Please let us know if we can assist you in any other way.

Comment: @Eric, can please you explain what it is exactly ?

Comment: @op this is an Apache library that might give you less headache when it comes to have websockets running compared to standard socket extension.

Comment: If you don't own/manage the server, you obviously can't enable extensions.  Your only option is to switch to a plan or another service that supports it.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions you've found are incorrect. The lines you're trying to insert into `php.ini` are for a Windows system - the equivalent extension files on Linux have a `.so` extension, not `.dll`, and are named somewhat differently.

**If they are present on your server**, you may be able to load this extension by naming it correctly:

```
extension = sockets.so
```

However, if this extension is not installed, attempting to load it this way will have no effect. You will need to ask your host's support team to install the extension.

Comment: I replaced the directives as you suggested. Still the same error is being faced. While calling go daddy support team they replied everything is fine from their side.

Comment: I tried by checking extension_loaded() function , but it returns false. So extension is not loading... Would there be problem at go daddy side ? or i would have to make some effort ?

Comment: I edited my question. Can you please suggest me alternative to this one. As I can't afford a vps or dedicated server.

Comment: The answer you've received from GoDaddy support seems to answer the question thoroughly. I see no reason to add anything here.